# CKEditor HTML4 validation to support HTML Emails

Tags: ckeditor, cakephp-2.3, html4

Several questions in one here but I suspect will all have the same answer.

Using the CKEditor in a CakePHP project where the content being edited is to make the html part of an email.

Most email applications don't fully support HTML net alone true HTML5.

An example of which is to center text in an email paragraph you use either *<p align=center>* or *<center></center>*

In the CKEditor when in source mode editing if do a <p align=center> and save it (or just toggle the source edit mode) it removes the align=center because in HTML5 that's no longer valid.

**How can I allow this in the CKEditor?**

**Can I enable HTML4 validation instead of HTML5?**

I also have a table in the template where half of it is edited in a field(textbox) called Header (the header of the email template) and another field called footer.

In the Header I want *<table><tr><td>*
In the Footer I want *</td></tr></table>*

Then my message content is placed in the *TD* cell between the header and footer.

However the CKEditor won't allow me to have an HTML TAG and not its closing TAG.
Any ideas on how to make this happen as well?

Regards

Ian

Answer (score 0):

To change the HTML that it's accepted by CKEditor, adjust its [ACF settings](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf). The simplest way is to allow everything:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

That won't solve the halve tables part.
For that you can try to use [config.protectedSource](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource), defining a rule for both the opening and closing parts, but taking care to add also something there that allows you to target only that table and not any other table that might be in the content.
(Of course the best solution would be to but that table outside the editor when you create the mail with all the parts)